# Insert one-many relationship data using a ViewModel EF ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, viewmodel

I am trying to figure out how to insert multiple rows of data using a viewmodel with a single postback. I am using EF and code first approach. The model I an having trouble with has one to many relationship. What I would like to do is that whenever a Person is created, multiple Tasks should be saved to the database along with a Person (different tables).

So far, I am only able to save the very first Task and not all.

My models are:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    [key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    Public class PersonData
    {
       public Person Person { get; set; }
       public Task Task { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
    @model Project.ViewModels.PersonData

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

       <fieldset>
       <legend>Event</legend>

       <div>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Event.Name)
       </div>
       <div id="taskdiv">
       </div>
       @*dynamically generated textboxes here*@

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // took few codes out here, but whats happening here is based on int value textboxes for Task appears
    for (var i = 1; i <= $count; i++) {
        $('#taskdiv').append('<div><label>Task #' + i + ' </label>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Task.Task)</div>');
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
       private Context db = new DBContext();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
       return View();
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(ViewModels.PersonData personData) 
    {           
       if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
           db.Person.Add(eventData.Person);
           db.Tasks.Add(eventData.Task);
           db.SaveChanges();        

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

At least I know that tasks are being passed. I tried few things like

```
foreach (char c in personData.Task.Task.AsEnumerable)
{ count += 1}
```

and received the correct amount of number. I thought using ViewModels are relatively common, but I didn't see what I would like to do in any tutorials or forums....

My goal is to be able to save multiple tasks per person with one postback. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you're outputting the textboxes with JavaScript? It's causing you a few problemms...

Comment: yes, task section is optional. What I actually have is a dropdownlist containing 0-5. Based on that value I am displaying appropriate number of textboxes for task. I thought about having all textboxes there and hiding/unhiding, but generating with jquery seemed cleaner.

Comment: Did you ever find an equitable solution for this? I'm running in to this exact same situation and I have  not found documentation that describes inserting data into the "child" and "parent" tables in a single view.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel you only have one Task, should be a list of tasks right?
When I do stuff like this I usually save the Person object first then add tasks to it using ajax.

The Method could look something like this.

```
public void SaveTasks(List<Task> tasks){
    //important that tasks already have personId --set on client side

    foreach(var task in Tasks){
      //do some validation
      db.Tasks.Add(task);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Comment: sorry I never used ajax and still very new to mvc, so I'm confused... also since I have list of task in Person object. Shouldn't that take care of inserting multiple tasks?